# INSERT INTO Statement only for those who don't have already an entry

Tags: sql, insert, exists

I have 2 tables: `cSc_UserClassSettings` and `cSc_User`

I want to `INSERT` all User in `cSc_UserClassSettings` from `cSc_User` using this `INSERT` Statement:

```
INSERT INTO [cSc_UserClassSettings]
       ([RSRC]
       ,[Deleted]
       ,[DateNew]
       ,[DateChanged]
       ,[UserNew]
       ,[UserChanged]
       ,[camosGUID]
       ,[UserGUID]
       ,[ClassName]
       ,[WriteByOpen]
       ,[DefaultReadAccess]
       ,[DefaultWriteAccess]
       ,[Summary])
SELECT
        0
       ,0
       ,getdate()
       ,NULL
       ,camosGUID
       ,NULL
       ,NEWID()
       ,camosGUID
       ,'cQ_RootOffer_C'
       ,0
       ,0
       ,0
       ,0
FROM [cSc_User]
```

But some users already have an entry in `cSc_UserClassSetting`s and for those it should not make an entry.

If it is neccessary cSc_UserClassSettings has a Foreign Key on cSc_User with `cSC_UserClassSettings.UserGUID = cSC_User.camosGUID`

I've tried this:

```
INSERT INTO [cSc_UserClassSettings]
       ([RSRC]
       ,[Deleted]
       ,[DateNew]
       ,[DateChanged]
       ,[UserNew]
       ,[UserChanged]
       ,[camosGUID]
       ,[UserGUID]
       ,[ClassName]
       ,[WriteByOpen]
       ,[DefaultReadAccess]
       ,[DefaultWriteAccess]
       ,[Summary])
SELECT
        0
       ,0
       ,getdate()
       ,NULL
       ,camosGUID
       ,NULL
       ,NEWID()
       ,camosGUID
       ,'cQ_RootOffer_C'
       ,0
       ,0
       ,0
       ,0
FROM [cSc_User]
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
select *
from cSc_UserClassSettings
where classname = 'cQ_RootOffer_C' and deleted = 0
)
```

But it returns 0 values.
Any ideas how I could solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the relationship between these two tables? any common column between these two?

Comment: yes. cSc_UserClassSettings has a Foreign Key on cSc_User with cSC_UserClassSettings.UserGUID = cSC_User.camosGUID. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert record in `cSc_UserClassSettings` from `cSC_User` table but those are not in already in `cSc_UserClassSettings` then you can try this Select Query

```
SELECT
        0
       ,0
       ,getdate()
       ,NULL
       ,camosGUID
       ,NULL
       ,NEWID()
       ,camosGUID
       ,'cQ_RootOffer_C'
       ,0
       ,0
       ,0
       ,0
FROM [cSc_User] 
WHERE cSC_User.camosGUID NOT IN (
                      Select UserGUID
                      From cSc_UserClassSettings
                      )
```